# Existence of the partial derivatives ${\delta^{2}f}\over {\delta x \delta y}$ and ${\delta f}\over {\delta x}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

The  question  is can  the  partial   double  derivative ${\delta^{2}f}\over {\delta x \delta y}$      exist  without  the  derivative ${\delta f}\over  {\delta x}$  existing?

I  don't  know , I  am  new  to  the  multi  variable  calculus  scene  and  totally  clueless  about  it.  Would  be  really  helpful  if  some  explanation  is  given  as  to  why   this  may    or  may  not  happen

Thanks.

Comment: Suggestion to the question (v1): Replace $\delta$ with $\partial$.

Answer (score 0):

If $f(x,y)=|x|$, then $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,y)$ does not exist for any $y$. Therefore certainly $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y\partial x}(0,y)$ does not exist, because it does not make sense to take the derivative of a function which is not even defined. On the other hand, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y)=0$ for all $(x,y)$, and thus $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\partial y}(x,y)=0$ for all $(x,y)$. The bottom line is that for functions which are not sufficiently smooth, the order of partial differentiation matters.